# Second computed function causes error in Knockout code

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

The Knockout code below applies tracks the values of the two textboxes using an observable and a computed observable.

Markup:

```
GBP:
<input type="textbox" data-bind="value: sendGbp" />
<br />
Exchange Rate: £1 GBP 
<br />
<input type="textbox" data-bind="value: sendFx" />
```

Javascript:

```
var transferItem = {
    receiveCurrencyCode : "JPY",
    exchangeRate : 123.223122
}

function viewModel(item) {

    var self = this;

    var initval = parseFloat(100).toFixed(2);
    self.sendGbp = ko.observable(initval);

    /** commented out error source
    self.labelFxRate = ko.computed(function() {
        return exchangeRate + " " + item.receiveCurrencyCode;
    });    
    **/

    self.sendFx = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return parseFloat(self.sendGbp() * item.exchangeRate).toFixed(2);
        },
        write: function (val) {
            var valGbp = parseFloat(val);
            self.sendGbp((valGbp / item.exchangeRate).toFixed(2));
        }
    });
}
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(transferItem));
```

This works fine until I want to add another computed observable to display the

This involves going commenting out the section in the viewModel code and adding this a databound label to the markup:

```
Exchange Rate: £1 GBP  = <label data-bind="text: labelFxRate" />
```

But this causes an error and the markup fails to render completely

What's the correct way of applying the second computed variable to show additional properties from the transferItem object?

A full work in progress version is on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WuvZD/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you must not use self-closing tags for label.
Also in your commented out code you used `return exchangeRate` but it should be `return item.exchangeRate`?

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WuvZD/4/

Comment: return exchangeRate was a typo when I was playing around on jsFiddle. But, yes - it was the self-closing label tag which was the error! Thanks!